# AS Level Matrices Proof

Tags: matrices, proof-writing

Show that for two 2x2 matrices A and B, where neither A nor B is the zero matrix Z, that if AB = Z then both A and B must be singular.

I understand the rule that det(AB) = det(A) x det(B), which shows that either A or B is singular, but I don't know how to show that both of them must be singular.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Suppsoe $A$ is non-singular, then the rank of $B$ is the same as the rank of $AB$.

Hence $B$ must be the zero matrix, which is a contradiction.

Similarly if $B$ is non-singular.

Hence both $A$ and $B$ are singular.

Edit:

Someone posted on the comment but it's now removed but I think it's much better than my approach.

Suppose $A$ is invertible, then we can premultiply $A^{-1}$ to both sides of $AB=Z$ and obtain $B=Z$ which is a contradiction. Similarly, post-multiply $B^{-1}$ if $B$ is invertible.